# Is getc() defined after it has returned EOF?

Tags: c, io

I use `getc();` in a C excercise, and after looking back on the program I noticed something weird. I assumed that the file given on the command line arguments contains at least one byte. (It calls `getc();` twice in a row without checking for `EOF`. After trying it on an empty file it still worked smoothly. My question is: **is the behaviour of `getc();` on a file pointer that's been exhausted (EOF has been reached and not rewinded) undefined or will it always continue to return EOF?**

I think I could expand this question to all the I/O functions in the C STL, please clarify this in your answer too.

Here is the code for the program. The program is supposed to strip a C/C++ source file from all comments (and it works perfectly).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int state = 0; // state: 0 = normal, 1 = in string, 2 = in comment, 3 = in block comment
    int ignchar = 0; // number of characters to ignore
    int cur, next; // current character and next one
    FILE *fp; // input file

    if (argc == 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s file.c\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    if ((fp = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file.\n");
        return 2;
    }

    cur = getc(fp); // initialise cur, assumes that the file contains at least one byte
    while ((next = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
        switch (next) {
            case '/':
                if (!state && cur == '/') {
                    state = 2; // start of comment
                    ignchar = 2; // don't print this nor next char (//)
                } else if (state == 3 && cur == '*') {
                    state = 0; // end of block comment
                    ignchar = 2; // don't print this nor next char (*/)
                }
                break;
            case '*':
                if (!state && cur == '/') {
                    state = 3; // start of block comment
                    ignchar = 2; // don't print this nor next char (/*)
                }
                break;
            case '\n':
                if (state == 2) {
                    state = 0;
                    ignchar = 1; // don't print the current char (cur is still in comment)
                }
                break;
            case '"':
                if (state == 0) {
                    state = 1;
                } else if (state == 1) {
                    state = 0;
                }
        }

        if (state <= 1 && !ignchar) putchar(cur);
        if (ignchar) ignchar--;
        cur = next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but just for clarity, is this C, or C++? It looks like C, but I'd rather check than just edit.

Comment: It's C, I thought it could apply to C++ too, but I'll remove the tag to reduce ambiguity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stdio files keep an "eof" flag that's set the first time end-of-file is reached and can only be reset by calling `clearerr` or performing a successful `fseek` or `rewind`. Thus, once `getc` returns `EOF` once, it will keep returning `EOF`, even if new data becomes available, unless you use one of the aforementioned methods for clearing the eof flag.

Some non-conformant implementations may immediately make new data available. This behavior is harmful and can break conformant applications.

Comment: Note that traditional Unix systems had the broken behavior, and some modern systems may copy this "for compatibility". So I would avoid relying on either behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Logically, I think it should return `EOF` forever.

[getc](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getc.html) is defined in terms of [fgetc](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgetc.html).

> The getc() function shall be equivalent to fgetc() , except that if it
>   is implemented as a macro it may evaluate stream more than once, so the
>   argument should never be an expression with side effects.

The documentation for `fgetc` says:

> If the end-of-file indicator for the stream is set, or if the stream
>   is at end-of-file, the end-of-file indicator for the stream shall be set
>   and fgetc() shall return EOF.

And "is at end-of-file" can be determined by calling [feof](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/feof.html).

The documentation for `feof` says:

> The feof() function shall return non-zero if and only if the
>       end-of-file indicator is set for stream.

So unless something happens to clear the end-of-file indicator, it should continue returning `EOF` forever.

Comment: Is there any reason to use `getc();` over `fgetc();` then since `getc();` might be implemented in a macro thus possible multiple evaluation. (Apart from saving one character).

Comment: On most historical systems, `getc` was a macro that poked at the `FILE` internals inline and only made a function call if the buffer was empty. Modern standards require `getc` to be thread-safe under multiple threads reading from the same `FILE`, so macro definitions have gone out of style, but in principle a modern implementation could still use a macro if it could efficiently detect that only one thread is running.

Answer (score 1):

If the `EOF` flag on the stream is set, `getc` should return `EOF` (and if you keep calling `getc`, it should keep returning `EOF`).

Comment: So after the `EOF` flag on the stream is set `getc();` should always return `EOF`, even if you call it a thousand times. And `fseek();` removes the flag if you rewind, I assume?