# Is it possible for me to remove this last if statement?

Tags: c

I've written a small utility to open up executables and spit out certain printable strings it finds.

It works fine but I was wondering, is there some way I could remove one of these if statements?  I was trying to see how I could arrange my conditionals so I wouldn't need the 3 different if statements but I don't see how I can do it with the current structure.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_STR_SIZE 0x666
#define MIN_STR_SIZE 0x5

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    int ch;
    int pos = 0;
    FILE* f;
    char buff[MAX_STR_SIZE];

    if (argc>1 && (f=fopen(argv[1], "rb")))
    {
        while ((ch=getc(f)) != EOF)
        {
            if (ch >= ' ' && ch <= 'z') // is printable char?
            {
                buff[pos++] = ch;
                buff[pos] = '\0';
                if (pos == (MAX_STR_SIZE-1))  // is current string > max length?
                {
                    printf("%08x: %s\n", ftell(f), &buff[0]);
                    pos = 0;
                }
            }
            else // non-printable char, print any string in buffer and start over
            {
                if (pos > (MIN_STR_SIZE - 1)) // is current string > min string?
                {
                    printf("%08x: %s\n", ftell(f), &buff[0]); // print current string
                }
                pos = 0;
            }
        }

        if (pos > (MIN_STR_SIZE - 1)) // any remaining string left to print?
        {
            printf("%08x: %s\n", ftell(f), &buff[0]);
        }

        fclose(f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Retagged to C, there is no C++ in this question.

Comment: As you seem to be a careful coder, I want to add that your "printable" test falsely assumes that the range of printable characters is contiguous and has fixed start- and endpoints. Since this is not true (think EBCDIC, 8-bit ASCII, or the letter 'ü'), I suggest using `isprint()` from `ctype.h`, hence relying on the host environment to know what actually constitutes a printable character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this version eliminates most of the if statements (or at least collapses them together:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_STR_SIZE 0x666
#define MIN_STR_SIZE 0x5

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    int ch;
    int pos = 0;
    FILE* f;
    char buff[MAX_STR_SIZE];

    if (argc>1 && (f=fopen(argv[1], "rb")))
    {
        while ((ch = getc(f)) != EOF)
        {
            pos = 0;
            while (ch >= ' ' && ch <= 'z' && pos < (MAX_STR_SIZE-1)) {
                buff[pos++] = ch;
                ch = getc(f);
            }
            if (pos > (MIN_STR_SIZE - 1)) // is current string > min string?
            {
                buff[pos] = '\0';
                printf("%08x: %s\n", ftell(f), buff);
            }
        }

        fclose(f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the if (ch >= ' ' && ch <= 'z') even necessary anymore? It seems like it would work without it.

Comment: Yes, that was unnecessary, as was the check for EOF in the inner loop. I've updated the code to reflect those changes.

Comment: excellent! Thank you, this is much nicer.  I've also switched to using the isprint function as pointed out by Nawaz.

Comment: @DRH: What if inside the while loop `ch = getc(f);` reaches `EOF`?

Comment: @Nawaz, then isprint will return false, it will break out of that loop, print if necessary, and when getc(f) is called again in the outer loop it will return EOF again.  Right?

Comment: @KingNestor: I'm not sure if `getc()` in the outer loop will return EOF again! That is why I asked it.

Comment: @Nawaz, I wasn't sure either.  I found this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753869/is-getc-defined-after-it-has-returned-eof

Answer (score 3):

The last `if` seems to be necessary for the current logic of the code.

However, the check in your code is not entirely correct. Why don't you use [`isprint()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/isprint/) function to check whether a character is printable or not? Something like this:

```
if (isprint(c)) // is printable char?
{
  //c is printable
}
```